# Removing string from element in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a data frame where the output is something along this:

```
     VALUE     pat         animal   model
    <dbl>     <chr>        <chr>     <chr>
 1 0.0000000   14 bunny    bunny     semi
 2 0.0000021  911 Bunny    Bunny     semi
 3 0.0000093  922 BUNNY    BUNNY     semi
 4 0.0000118  629 Bunny    Bunny     semi
 5 0.0000203  807 Bunny    Bunny     semi
 6 0.0000245  263 Bunny    Bunny     semi
 7 0.0001229 1015 BUNNY    BUNNY     semi
 8 0.4401012  401 bunny    bunny     semi
 9 0.5979202  568 bunny    bunny     semi
```

I don't know why the dataset is like that, but as you can see, the `pat` column has a value, and then the same string as can be seen in the `animal` column.
What I would like is to remove the `bunny` string from the pat column for all entries of course, so that the value is just by itself.

Is there an easy way to do this, also keeping in mind, that there are different variations of `bunny`, i.e. capitals letters etc.

Comment: `df$pat = as.numeric(sub("\\s[a-zA-Z]+$", "", trimws(df$pat)))`

Comment: OR  assuming that the value you are looking for is always an initial number   `sub("(\\d+).*", "\\1", df$pat)`

Comment: G5W, you're solution worked like a charm. Unfortunately, the other suggestion made everything NA instead... Make an answer if you want rep :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Given that there is not a reproducible dataset I had to do some data manipulation to get it how it in the same format you posted.

```
require(stringr)

k <- read.table(text = "VALUE     pat         animal   model
  1 0.0000000   14_bunny    bunny     semi
2 0.0000021  911_Bunny    Bunny     semi
3 0.0000093  922_BUNNY    BUNNY     semi
4 0.0000118  629_Bunny    Bunny     semi
5 0.0000203  807_Bunny    Bunny     semi
6 0.0000245  263_Bunny    Bunny     semi
7 0.0001229 1015_BUNNY    BUNNY     semi
8 0.4401012  401_bunny    bunny     semi
9 0.5979202  568_bunny    bunny     semi")

k$pat <- stringr::str_replace(k$pat,"_", " ")
k$nums <- str_extract(k$pat,"\\d+")
k$nums_format <- as.numeric(k$nums)

k
      VALUE        pat animal model nums nums_format
1 0.0000000   14 bunny  bunny  semi   14          14
2 0.0000021  911 Bunny  Bunny  semi  911         911
3 0.0000093  922 BUNNY  BUNNY  semi  922         922
4 0.0000118  629 Bunny  Bunny  semi  629         629
5 0.0000203  807 Bunny  Bunny  semi  807         807
6 0.0000245  263 Bunny  Bunny  semi  263         263
7 0.0001229 1015 BUNNY  BUNNY  semi 1015        1015
8 0.4401012  401 bunny  bunny  semi  401         401
9 0.5979202  568 bunny  bunny  semi  568         568

str(k)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ VALUE      : num  0.00 2.10e-06 9.30e-06 1.18e-05 2.03e-05 ...
 $ pat        : chr  "14 bunny" "911 Bunny" "922 BUNNY" "629 Bunny" ...
 $ animal     : Factor w/ 3 levels "bunny","Bunny",..: 1 2 3 2 2 2 3 1 1
 $ model      : Factor w/ 1 level "semi": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ nums       : chr  "14" "911" "922" "629" ...
 $ nums_format: num  14 911 922 629 807 ...
```